# How to solve this error:-Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')

Tags: salesforce1-app, json

My code is break on line 2 -json.deserialize and

> responseString::::::::::[{
>     "key": "freelancer__zugu_4432_buqe", 
>     "success": "Data saved for organization id."
>   }]

`List<parserClass> cleanCrmKeyList = List<parserClass>)JSON.deserialize(responseString, List<parserClass>.class);`

Comment: Please post your `parserClass`.

Comment: There's probably some XML in your response string.

Answer (score 1):

You should deserialize **JSON** String using `Map` like this:

```
List<String> jsonString = new List<String> {'{ \"key\": \"freelancer__zugu_4432_buqe\", \"success\": \"Data saved for organization id.\" }'};
Map<String,Object> cleanCrmKeyList = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString[0]);
System.debug('key:'+cleanCrmKeyList.get('key'));
System.debug('success:'+cleanCrmKeyList.get('success'));
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: String responseString = res.getbody();
        responseString = '['+responseString+']';
     
        if(responseString == null){
         ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please on the server'));
        }      
        List<parserClass> cleanCrmKeyList =
            (List<parserClass>)JSON.deserialize(responseString, List<parserClass>.class);

Comment: aprimeBeta__APCleanCrmKey__c apiKey = new aprimeBeta__APCleanCrmKey__c();
        apiKey.Name = 'Clean CEM Key';
        apiKey.aprimeBeta__Key__c = cleanCrmKeyList[0].key;
        apiKey.aprimeBeta__ResponseStatus__c = cleanCrmKeyList[0].success;
        if(apiKey != null){
            insert apiKey;       
        }else{
          ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Already Key present'));
        }
            return null;       please look on this code how can i manage map on this

Comment: @Himanshujasuja post your code in your question instead of posting it in comments